# How to fetch data from three tables in sqlite3 using flask

Tags: sql, sqlite

There are three tables `comments` `users` `posts` 
`comments` has three attributes - `postid` `userid` `comments` 
`users` has two attributes - `userid` `username` 
`posts` has two attributes - `posturl` `postid`

I have only posturl. I want to fetch comments and username with respective post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this statement:

```
SELECT posts.posturl, users.username, comments.comments
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN 
    (comments INNER JOIN users ON comments.userid = users.userid) ON posts.postid = comments.postid
WHERE (((posts.posturl)='url'));
```

replace `url` with your url.

Comment: thnx for this solution.